# Error on inserting data in SQL Server db from Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, excel, clr

I am inserting data from an Excel sheet to SQL Server 2005 db. I am getting this error randomly, sometimes after 20-30 records and sometimes after 1000s.  I am unable to find the reason.

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

> The CLR has been unable to transition
>   from COM context 0x21a7b0 to COM
>   context 0x21a920 for 60 seconds. The
>   thread that owns the destination
>   context/apartment is most likely
>   either doing a non pumping wait or
>   processing a very long running
>   operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has
>   a negative performance impact and may
>   even lead to the application becoming
>   non responsive or memory usage
>   accumulating continually over time. To
>   avoid this problem, all single
>   threaded apartment (STA) threads
>   should use pumping wait primitives
>   (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and
>   routinely pump messages during long
>   running operations.

Can anybody tell me what this error is and why I am getting this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: [This](http://forums.asp.net/p/1493688/3517149.aspx) thread seems to directly answer your question and the steps involved to solve it.

If you want to learn more check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172233.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing connections when you are done with them? It may be that connections are left open, consuming the maximum number of connections available to your application, and eventually timing out.